# What is wrong with my recurrence data string?

Tags: google-calendar-api, recurrence, rfc2445

I'm trying to create recurrence rule to export my timetable to `Google Calendar`, but I'm doing something wrong.

The string is the following:

```
'DTSTART;TZID=Europe/London:20100822T080000\r\nRRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;COUNT=5;BYDAY=Mo,Tu,We,Th,Fr;UNTIL=20100827T164500Z\r\nDTEND;TZID=Europe/London:20100822T180000\r\n'
```

It is working fine if you will take off the part with `UNTIL` (this part which I hard coded for test: `;UNTIL=20100827T164500Z`) but with `UNTIL` there it's not working(and I need that `UNTIL` to be there).

I was looking to the document `RFC244`5 and I don't find what can be wrong with until.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

COUNT and UNTIL are mutually exclusive.  See [Recurrence Rule](http://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/recur.html) definition.